# Android Line Break on htmlText

Tags: android, html, mysql

[image]

I'm trying to create an item description in a form of a list.

Example:

1. Medium
2. 100% Cotton
3. Etc

This description is sotred in my database, text as a data type.

The problem :

Im gettin all description in one line, I´ve tried to insert line breaks by replacing "." for "\n" and using HTML tags but doesnt seem to work.

```
        htmlText = post.cloths_description;


    String text = "<html><head>"
            + "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> "
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #000000;}"
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + htmlText
            + "</body></html>";
```

Result : 1. Medium 2. 100% Cotton 3. Etc

Any ideas on what else could I do ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use line breaks.

```
<br />
```

## This is elementary HTML.

Update:
Try this:

```
Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
```

Comment: I tried HTML tags but didnt work, tried anyways and this is the result :
1.test <br /> 2.test <br /> 3.test  also 1.test "<br />" 2.test '<br />' 3.test

Comment: are you printing this on a text view or a web view?\